# NSMutableArray Sorting and grouping with memory Optimisation

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, nsmutablearray, nsarray

NSArray has ItemObject's in it. This ItemObject's are not grouped based on ItemID

The Sample of the json is displayed below:
You will note the itemIDs "a123","a124". There can be n number of itemIDs.

```
[
    {
        "ItemName": "John",
        "ItemID": "a123"
    },
    {
        "ItemName": "Mary",
        "ItemID": "a124"
    },
    {
        "ItemName": "Larry",
        "ItemID": "a123"
    },
    {
        "ItemName": "Michel",
        "ItemID": "a123"
    },
    {
        "ItemName": "Jay",
        "ItemID": "a124"
    }
]
```

The above response is stored in NSArray as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *itemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ItemObject *obj=[[ItemObject alloc] init];
obj.itemName=@"John";
obj.itemID=@"a123";
[itemArray addObject:obj]

.....

ItemObject *objN=[[ItemObject alloc] init];
objN.itemName=@"Jay";
objN.itemID=@"a124";
[itemArray addObject:objN].
```

This shows, if there are N items in JSON, then it will create a array of N items.

The above item is displayed correctly in UItableView.

Now, if want to sort them and put them in NSMutableArray group wise what will be optimal way to code it, with less memory footprint to be consumed. [i.e sorting + grouping]
I am trying to achieve the below:

```
NSMutableArray *itemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
at index 0: NSArray with itemID "a123"
at index 1: NSArray with itemID "a124"
```

Since, available ItemIds, are dynamic, as I explained there can be "N" number of itemId's.

Step 1:
So, I first need to find the available itemId's.

Step 2:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *itemID in itemIDS){
 NSArray *itemsForID=[itemArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"itemID MATCHES %@",itemID]];
[myArray addObject:itemsForID];
}
```

myArray is the expected result.
But using filterUsingPredicate "N" number of times will be time and memory consuming.

Any, help Appreciated.

Comment: Do you have control over the itemID's coming in from the JSON, or do you need to add new objects and assign them the next available ID? As far as the grouping, do you want your final structure to be an array of arrays with each of the internal arrays having objects all with the same itemID?

Comment: Depending on how you're going to use the resulting object, you might consider using a dictionary where the keys are the itemID's and the values would be an array of all the ItemObjects whose itemID matches that key.

Comment: @rdelmar I dont have any control over the itemID's. They are received in the response. Final structure is array within array's of respective ID.

Comment: Well, that structure will be quite inefficient. If you want to be more efficient, then a dictionary with the itemID's as the keys would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below code?

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemID"  ascending:YES];
[itemArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: Nice answer but it should assign the result to myArray.

Comment: It will good to have this code snippet in my code.But, i am looking for memory and time optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You could persist your data as NSManagedObjects. Then you can use an [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as data source for your table (you set a sort descriptor and a section name key path to it):

```
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
        managedObjectContext:context
        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
        cacheName:nil];
```

You can also set the batch size (the max number of objects taken from the DB at a time).

Hope this helps!